# PackageManager not returing application's icon

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get the icon of an application's notification. The listener works perfectly, but for most of the apps I tried (telegram, signal, android messages...) I cannot seem to get the app's icon.
Here is the code where I try to get the icon:

```kotlin
    private fun getIcon(notification: StatusBarNotification, context: Context): Bitmap {
        val packageManager = context.packageManager
        return try {
            Bitmap.createBitmap(drawableToBitmap(packageManager.getApplicationIcon(notification.packageName)))
        } catch (exception: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(10, 10, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8)
        }
    }

    private fun drawableToBitmap(drawable: Drawable): Bitmap {
        if (drawable is BitmapDrawable) {
            if (drawable.bitmap != null) {
                return drawable.bitmap
            }
        }

        val bitmap: Bitmap = if (drawable.intrinsicWidth <= 0 || drawable.intrinsicHeight <= 0) {
            Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        } else {
            Bitmap.createBitmap(
                drawable.intrinsicWidth,
                drawable.intrinsicHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )
        }

        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        drawable.draw(canvas)
        return bitmap
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the icons you should use both class & package names instead of only using the package name. If the app supports changing icons or has more than one launcher activity this works much better.

```
fun getIcon(context: Context, packageName: String, className: String): Drawable? {
    var drawable: Drawable? = null
    try {

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        intent.setClassName(packageName, className)
        drawable = context.packageManager.getActivityIcon(intent)

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        try {
            drawable = context.packageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageName)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    return drawable
}
```

This function returns the icon drawable or returns null if it fails. It tries to get the icon using both package and class names at first but if it fails it uses only package name. You can just use the package name one if you don't want to use the class name as well.

If it's still just catching the exception every time and you know the app is installed, you probably lack some permissions. You can also try again with `targetSdkVersion 29` instead of `targetSdkVersion 30` since 30 adds some limitations to this kind of functions but I am not sure if those affect getting the icons as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I go about getting the class name?

Comment: @TheZadok42 the variables name is `name` in the `ActivityInfo` object

Comment: sorry for the noob question, but can you elaborate? How can I get that information from the notification alone?

Comment: @TheZadok42uh sorry, I thought you had this object already. I have a launcher and I just looked at my code in it. I just query all apps information using `packageManager` and when I run the `queryIntentActivities' function it returns a list of `ActivityInfo` objects. It has the apps name, icon, package name, class name etc. I dont really know how you can get it from a notification and I dont think you even need that. Just use the second icon function in my original reply. (`context.packageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageName`)

Comment: The thing is, I cannot seem to get icons for apps like the messaging app (com.google.android.apps.messaging) or any other apps for that matter. I get "NameNotFound" errors

Comment: Is your app targeting SDK 30? Can you give it another try with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />` in your manifest? Although I dont know if it affects your problem or not.

Comment: Glad to hear that!